# Looking for equivalent of ST_ContainsProperly for selecting features in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygon, overlapping-features, select-by-location

I'm looking for a solution to select islands (non-black polygons) in polygon A (black).

I think, in PostGIS [`ST_ContainsProperly()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ContainsProperly.html) will do this task. But I'm looking for an equivalent solution in PyQGIS.

The function shall only return `True` when checking the green polygon. Checking the grey MultiPolygon shall return `False`, because it is partially outside and the red polygon `False` because it touches the border

[image]

I tried the code from [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210874/determining-if-polygon-lies-completly-in-another-polygon-or-only-partly-using-qg)

```py
path_1 = r"C:\temp\test_poly.shp"
path_2 = r"C:\temp\test_poly_umr.shp"

layerB = QgsVectorLayer(path_1, "layerB", "ogr")
layerA = QgsVectorLayer(path_2, "layerA", "ogr")

if layerA.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerA)

if layerB.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerB)
    
island = False
for bF in layerB.getFeatures():
    for aF in layerA.getFeatures():
         if aF.geometry().intersects(bF.geometry()): 
            if bF.geometry().contains(aF.geometry()): 
                island = True
    print(bF[0], ' ', island)
    island = False
```

[image]

... but it returns `island=True` for Polzgon #5 instead of polygon #3 (as expected)

Comment: It would appear that both methods you tried yield the same result. Are you sure your input data is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check if A's boundary intersects B's boundary. You can use this script.

```py
# ...
# previous lines
# ...

island = False
for aF in layerA.getFeatures():
    
    # get aF's boundary (=line)
    aF_boundary = aF.geometry().convertToType(QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry)
    
    for bF in layerB.getFeatures():        
        if aF.geometry().contains(bF.geometry()):

            # get bF's boundary (=line)
            bF_boundary = bF.geometry().convertToType(QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry) 
       
            if not bF_boundary.intersects(aF_boundary):
                island = True
                
        print(bF[0], ' ', island)
        island = False
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use the [6] `within` predicate with the ["Extract By Location"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#id4).

```py
container = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('container')[0]
islands = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('islands')[0]

selected = processing.run("native:extractbylocation",
                            {'INPUT':islands,
                            'PREDICATE':[6],
                            'INTERSECT':container,
                            'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
                        )['OUTPUT']

selected.setName('selected')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(selected)
```

In the figure, the hatched polygon is the result of Extract by Location.

[image]